# SQL Server: Increment row value depending on previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the columns `id` and `value`. I'd like to create a column that groups the `id`. If a row's current `value` equals `0` then a new group in `ideal_group` will be created.

Table:

```
id | value | ideal_group
1    1       1
2    1       1
3    1       1
4    0       2
5    1       2
6    0       3
7    0       4
```

I'm thinking the solution should be something like:

```
SET @n = 1;
SELECT id, 
       CASE 
            WHEN value = 0 THEN @n = @n + 1 
       ELSE @n END AS ideal_group
```

But I'd prefer not to use an counter variable. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: What should be returned when the 1st row has a `0`?  0 or 1?

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code, I assumed, that values in `value` column are only `1`s and `0`s:

```
select id,
       value,
       sum(1 - value) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) + 1 [ideal_group]
from MY_TABLE
```

More general solution (without mentioned assumption):

```
select id,
       value,
       sum(case value when 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) + 1 [ideal_group]
from MY_TABLE
```

Comment: @PaulKaram Your suggestion wouldn't work, also, I add 1 to this column and it's exactly like OP wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> create table tbl (id int, value int);
> insert into tbl values
> (1, 1),
> (2, 1),
> (3, 1),
> (4, 0),
> (5, 1),
> (6, 0),
> (7, 0);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select id,
>        value,
>        1 + sum(iif(value = 0, 1, 0)) over 
>                 (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as ideal_group
> from   tbl
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | value | ideal_group
> -: | ----: | ----------:
>  1 |     1 |           1
>  2 |     1 |           1
>  3 |     1 |           1
>  4 |     0 |           2
>  5 |     1 |           2
>  6 |     0 |           3
>  7 |     0 |           4
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aea51f38299547f73eb492d02d3628ef)*

Comment: Last remark, why is everybody using `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` instead of the shorter `rows unbounded preceding` syntax? Here the default of `current row` is a good one :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you reversed the 1 and 0 and it was only 1 or 0 this would be easier.

```
declare @T table (id int primary key, val int);
insert into @T values 
       (1, 1)
     , (2, 1)
     , (3, 1)
     , (4, 0)
     , (5, 1)
     , (6, 0)
     , (7, 0);
select t.id, t.val 
     , case when t.val = 0 then 1 else 0 end as trig
     , sum(case when t.val = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by t.id) + 1 as grp
from @T t 
order by t.id; 

id          val         trig        grp
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           0           1
2           1           0           1
3           1           0           1
4           0           1           2
5           1           0           2
6           0           1           3
7           0           1           4
```

Comment: You should add `rows unbounded preceding`, otherwise it defaults to `range unbounded preceding`, which might be less efficient. And might return a different result, e.g. add a 2nd row with `(6,0)`.

Comment: @dnoeth I can't add a second row.  I made that the primary key.   If they don't have a unique sort the question does not make much sense.

Comment: Of course, in this case, but the common rule is still *don't use RANGE unless you actually need it*. The optimizer might not know about uniqueness and then applies RANGE logic.